# Selecting rows with top n values based on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the one below where all IDs are unique and columns A, B and C hold values between 0 and 1.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1, 0.7, 0, 0.5, 0.3, 0.3], 'B' :[0.6, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.9, 0.3], 'C':[0.6, 0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 0.5], 'ID':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']} )
```

| A | B | C | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.6 | 0.6 | a |
| 0.7 | 0.1 | 0.3 | b |
| 0 | 0.4 | 0.6 | c |
| 0.5 | 0.3 | 0.8 | d |
| 0.3 | 0.9 | 0.9 | e |
| 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.5 | f |

I want to keep just the top n values of A, B and C, so that for n = 2 the dataframe looks as follow:

| A | B | C | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.6 | NaN | a |
| 0.7 | NaN | NaN | b |
| NaN | NaN | 0.8 | d |
| NaN | 0.9 | 0.9 | e |

Doing df.set_index('ID')['A'].nlargest(2).reset_index() gives me:

| ID | A |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 0.7 |

Is there a simpler way than doing this 3 times and joining the datasets?

Comment: Please read this: [how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) e.g. use `df[['tags', 'elements']].iloc[:5].to_dict()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `nlargest`

```
out = df.set_index('ID').apply(lambda x : x.nlargest(n=2))
Out[654]: 
      A    B    C
ID               
a   1.0  0.6  NaN
b   0.7  NaN  NaN
d   NaN  NaN  0.8
e   NaN  0.9  0.9
```